# Javascript web app displays server error although I don't use any server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have a React application which I display by selecting `index.html` and "Open in browser."

My `index.html` file displays my `Main.js` object in the following way:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="content"></div>
    <!-- build:js -->
    <script src="app/Main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error in Goggle Chrome Developer Tools.

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

However, I don't use a server and I don't think I need one since I am displaying the `index.html` page directly in the browser.

Another error I get(which may be related) is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I get this on the third line of the following code:

```
 render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Res</h1>
        <ResE data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
```

Again, I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: have a look in the developer tool of Chrome. which resource could not be loaded? do you have `Main.js` in your `app` directory?

Comment: How can I see that?
If you're asking where the error appears, it appears in `/src/css/base.css`
Yes, I do have `Main.js` in `app`

Comment: Probably a resource could not be found. To see the Developer Tool of Chrome press F12. `the server responded with a ...` is a generic error it doesn't mean that you have a server

Comment: where do you declare to load the css. I cannot see it in your code! Do you have that file in /src/css folder?

Comment: Indeed, I couldn't find that css file in my project. However, the second error remains.

Comment: If you want to use jsx, you need a jsx transformer.

Comment: I do have a transformer.

Comment: The `render` function you pasted is missing a right bracket `}` at the end.